# I wrote a method in C++ to print preorder of tree class but it shows segmentation error

Tags: c++, function, recursion, tree, definition

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class tree
{
    public:
    int data;
    tree *left;
    tree *right;

    tree* add_left(int data)
    {
        tree *t = new tree;
        left = t;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
        t->data = data;
        return t;
    }


    tree* add_right(int data)
    {
        tree *t = new tree;
        right = t;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
        t->data = data;
        return t;
    }


    void preorder()
    {
        if(left==NULL && right==NULL)
            cout<<data<<" ";
        else
        {
        cout<<data<<" ";
        left->preorder();
        right->preorder();
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    tree *a = new tree;
    a->data = 10;
    tree *t = a->add_left(15);
    tree *b = a->add_right(20);
    tree *ne = t->add_left(30);
    a->preorder();
    return 0;
}
```

It just prints 
10 15 30 
and then segmentation error.
It is a binary tree. Add left and right adds nodes to the left and right side of the tree respectively.
The preorder should be 10 15 30 20, but for some reason, it does not print 20.

Comment: Some unrelated comments: 1) `add_left` and `add_right` casually overwrite pointers without freeing the subtrees first. 2) your `tree` destructor should free its children, and you should strive to implement the rest of the Rule of Three (or Five) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the function id incorrect. It can be called when the current pointer is equal to `nullptr` that is when either left pointer or right pointer is a null-pointer.

Rewrite the function the following way

```
void preorder() const
{
    cout << data << " ";
    if ( left ) left->preorder();
    if ( right ) right->preorder();
}
```

If to call this member function for your tree then the output will be

```
10 15 30 20
```

Pay attention to that the function is declared with the qualifier `const` because it does not change the tree.

A more flexible function definition can look the following way

```
std::ostream & preorder( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
{
    os << data << " ";
    if ( left ) left->preorder();
    if ( right ) right->preorder();

    return os;
}
```

In this case you will be able to write the list into a file.

Answer (score 1):

You code crashes because `right` is null while you calls `preorder()` on it, change `if(left==NULL && right==NULL)` to `if(left==NULL || right==NULL)` or other checks to avoid a null pointer dereference.

Comment: What about nodes with just one child?

Comment: Then you'll no longer have a preorder traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Change your tree::preorder method like this:

```
void preorder()
{
    cout<<data<<" ";

    if(left)
    {
     left->preorder();   
    }

    if(right)
    {
     right->preorder();   
    }
}
```